# Hide/display textbox as well as its label withouth knowing ids

Tags: javascript, textbox, radio-button

I'm currently building a table with several cells containing a radio with a series of textboxes.
I want each radio to make a textbox appear when clicked as well as the textbox label. Here is something that's working when knowing id for label or radio (the problem is reduced to what's inside one table cell):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" id="quests'+id+'">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <label>Question?</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="+QuestionID+_1" value="1" />
        <label for="'+QuestionID+'_1">Yes</label>

        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="+QuestionID+_0" value="0" />
        <label for="'+QuestionID+'_0">No</label>
        </fieldset>

<input type="text" name="textarea" style="width:80%; display:none;" id="comment_+QuestionID+"><label for "comment_+QuestionID+" class="labelhide" id="Test1">Test</label>
<input type="text" name="textarea1" style="width:80%; display:none;" id="comment_+QuestionID+"><label for "comment_+QuestionID+" class=labelhide id="Test2">Test</label>
        <br />
        </div>
```

and here is the JS

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {
$('input[type=text]').toggle($.trim(this.value)=='1');
document.getElementById("Test1").style.display = 'inline';});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Onysius/5WF25/2/

I'd like to have the same kind of behavior for the radio except I want it to toggle on only the 1st next textbox with its label without having to enter the corresponding name or id of the radio (table is generated by a python script with many textboxes under many radios so I don't want to create a specific function for each radio), textbox or label. The overall shape as to stay the same also (namely textbox below radio).

Is there a way to do that with a general form JavaScript (additional css is permitted-it currently uses a none display option for label class) ? To be clear my only trouble right now are the last 2 lines in the JS (I could easily set no name for the radio in the first line to apply it to any radio in the table) I don't actually know how to target just the next textbox after the radio with its associated label.

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something these lines to inject the textarea you want dynamically next to the item and retain the the name for tracking what comments goes to which radio and not having to create a textarea for each radio:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="c" id="quests'+id+'">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <label>Question?</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" />
            <label for="'+QuestionID+'_1">Yes</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" />
            <label for="'+QuestionID+'_0">No</label>
            </fieldset>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var name=$(this).attr('name')
    var html='<input type="text" name="textarea" style="width:80%;" id="comment_'+name+'"><label for "comment_'+name+'">Test</label>';

    $('input[name="'+name+'"]:last').next('label').after(html);
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/SzjL2/

Comment: This really helps with attribute calls. Yet it is not quite exactly what I'm looking for your fiddle helped me get the exact form I wanted. Here is the edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Onysius/SzjL2/2/. My next issue will be to toggle on additional textboxes when the first ones receive input I should manage to do so with what you gave me here. Thanks a lot

Comment: That's great stuff, happy to help, if you have an additional question outside the scope of the original question, mark this question as answered and post the other question. But if you want a quick answer just check if it already exists before inserting a new textarea.